# user.save returns false in console, but true when done via the UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a programming/rails beginner, and have encountered a bug I cannot wrap my head around.

I'm using/learning about the "has_secure_password" method. When I try and create a user in my console with a mismatched password/confirm_password, the console returns false and the error is "Password confirmation doesn't match Password". But, when I try and do the same thing within the UI given the below code (+ a view), it saves just fine! Now, notice that in my "user_params" method, I accidentally forgot to permit ":password_confirmation" which is how I noticed this issue in the first place. With that ":password_confirmation" added, the view throws an error but that's not the point. Why even without this is the new User record being successfully created with a mismatched password and password confirmation, even though it doesn't save in the console?

Here is my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, format: /\A\S+@\S+\z/, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
  validates :password, length: {minimum: 4, allow_blank: true}
end
```

And my User controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def index
    @users = User.all
end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        redirect_to @user, notice: "Thanks for signing up!"
    else
        render :new
    end
end

private
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the password_confirmation attribute is optional. When it isn't supplied to the model that has_secure_password, the model simply accepts the password.

When your password confirmation attribute isn't whitelisted in your controller via user_params, it isn't being passed to the model at all, which is why mismatches appears not to throw an error. In truth the validation isn't taking place at all.

This works in your console because it creates a user without involving a controller or strong parameter whitelisting.

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you. But follow up question: As a user, I should then be able to not supply a password confirmation at all and the record should still be created, because it's "optional". So what about my code (assuming i do whitelist password_confirmation) makes this field also required? Permitting is different from requiring, right? So it now correctly throws an error when everything is whitelisted in the controller, but now I don't understand why!

Comment: If you add it to the form, when the form is submitted the value will be empty for `password_confirmation` and will fail validation.

Comment: Just validate the presence of the password_confirmation in your user model.